# Para que serve memoryview em Python?

Tags: python, array

Eu estou lendo sobre arrays em Python e me deparei com uma função embutida chamada [`memoryview`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-memoryview). Entendi que uma diferença das listas para arrays é que nas últimas é possível usar o `memoryview`, enquanto, nas primeiras, não.

Por exemplo:

```py
from array import array
lista = [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0,
         4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 6.0, 7.0, 7.0, 8.0, 8.0]

# Retorna erro TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'list'
memoryview(lista)

# Mas isto funciona:
numbers = array('d', lista)
memoryview(numbers)
```

Eu imaginei que `memoryview` poderia ser uma espécie de equivalente à função `id` que, da forma como entendo, retorna o local na memória do objeto. Fiquei especialmente tentado por essa interpretação porque `memoryview(numbers)` retorna `<memory at 0x7fe5fca911f0>`, no meu caso. No entanto, `id(numbers)` retorna um valor completamente diferente.

Então para que serve `memoryview`? Qual a vantagem que o `memoryview` oferece de usar arrays em lugar de listas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resumidamente, no Python, os tipos básicos para manipular dados binários são `bytes` e `bytearray`. Eles, assim como *arrays*, por exemplo, são suportados pela classe `memoryview`, que usa o "***[buffer protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html#bufferobjects)***" para permitir o **acesso** à memória de outros objetos binários **sem a necessidade** de fazer cópia.

Confesso que é a primeira vez que deparo com isso no Python, mas o conceito me parece similar ao de [*slices*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-03-slices.html) do Rust. Acho interessante mencionar isso porque esse tipo de coisa é geralmente interessante ao se trabalhar com operações de "nível mais baixo", que é o nicho do Rust.

### Qual a vantagem?

A vantagem é justamente a rapidez e o menor custo para o acesso, uma vez que jamais será feita nenhum tipo de cópia para o acesso.

Por conta disso, você pode indexar e realizar [*slices*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/7445826) sem implicar em quase nenhum custo, já que, reitero, não haverá cópia.

Entenda o que *memoryview* retorna como uma "lente" que te permite ler os elementos diretamente "olhando para a memória", o que nem é o caso com os mecanismos mais "comuns" do Python. Um *slicing* em listas, por exemplo, copia as referências.

Como disse no começo da pergunta, o `memoryview` pode ser visto como uma API um pouco mais "*low level*" do Python. Na maioria dos casos, não fará diferença utilizar um *array* com *memoryview* ou uma lista normal. No entanto, existem casos em que o custo de cópias realmente pode implicar em um grande custo adicional. Nesses casos, é ideal utilizá-la.

### Por que não funciona com listas?

A API `memoryview` é válida somente para objetos que implementem o *buffer protocol*, o que não é o caso das listas.

Como o valor a ser "envolvido" pela *memoryview* deve possuir cada "elemento" com um mesmo tamanho de memória, você não é capaz de utilizar isso com listas, por exemplo, já que cada elemento dessa estrutura pode ocupar uma quantidade de memória diferente.

No seu caso *não deu certo* por causa disso: você estava utilizando uma lista, estrutura de dados que pode potencialmente ter valores com tamanhos variados. Mas, ao utilizar um array de *floats* (como feito no segundo exemplo da pergunta), funciona, já que cada elemento do array tem garantidamente o tamanho de um *float*, isto é, todos os elementos do array ocupam a mesma quantidade de memória. Portanto, o *memoryview* conseguirá fazer uma distinção clara e performática entre cada elemento, permitindo os acessos sem grandes custos.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Você poderia dar um exemplo desse ganho de performance no slicing? Eu tentei fazer um exemplo a partir da sua explicação, mas o resultado não foi o esperado. Veja no ideone: https://ideone.com/WMPFNu

Comment: Nesse exemplo, como o array tem pouquíssimos elementos, o custo de "indexar" um item da lista parece estar sendo menor ao custo de instanciar a _memoryview_. É importante se atentar ao detalhe de _otimização precoce_ (que me parece ser o caso aí). Na maioria das vezes, utilizar _memoryview_ pode acabar não agregando em tanto valor. No entanto, para operações evidentemente mais custosas, como trabalhar com listas com vários elementos (i.e. [este exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34257357/7445826) no StackOverflow em Inglês), a diferença já se torna perceptível. :)

Comment: Sendo um pouco mais dramático: https://ideone.com/jjYjib

Comment: Ótimo. Talvez seja o caso de adicionar este exemplo na sua resposta para futuros leitores dessa questão terem uma visão mais concreta das vantagens de performance do `memoryview`

Comment: Agora está nos comentários. :D

Comment: hhahahaha ... sim. Mas nem todos leem comentários e o link do ideone pode quebrar por alguma razão. De todo modo, foi apenas uma sugestão.